# Invalid syntax: from django import forms

Tags: django

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqIE4.png)
I wrote the following code in forms.py. I can't understand what is wrong with this. This gives invalid syntax

```
form django import forms

class contactForm(forms.Forms):
    name=forms.CharField(required=False,max_length=100,help_text='100 characters max.')
    email=forms.EmailField(required=True)
    comment=forms.CharField(required=True,widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Comment: What is the stack trace?

Comment: Paste what you are seeing in the yellow page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check the typo:** You need `forms.Form` and **not** `forms.Forms`.

```
class contactForm(forms.Form):
```

**Error:** write `from` instead of `form`

```
from django import forms
^^^^
```

Comment: i have edited the post. See the image link included at the starting

Comment: ohh. I didn't saw this spelling mistake. Thanks

Comment: @PrachiKatlam, Feel privileged to help you out.